# Pwncat-cs API docs doesn't provide much informations

Tags: security

I have been working on a project that I want to use pwncat-cs API in it (https://github.com/calebstewart/pwncat) but the docs is so uncomprehensive, so I want help from someone who did work on this tool or if there is any tools that do the same job, I need a tool that give me the power to get a reverse shell on a host then run some commands on that host using the script.

I tried the docs but it is uncomprehensive.